# IntelliJ Idea auto-complete for my own grails domain meta class methods?

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 10 IDE for my grails development and while it's great at working out the "standard" meta class methods on, for example, domain classes (save, findBy etc), it (obviously) can't pick up methods added by plugins or my own code.

While I don't expect the IDE to be able to pick these up automatically, I'm optimistically wondering if there's a way to tell IntelliJ that, for example, "myMethod" is added to all domain objects, and that it takes a map and returns "myType".

It's a long shot I know, but does anyone know how this might be done in config, a plugin, or by some smoke-and-mirrors so I can a) stop missing simple, stupid typos and b) get some auto-complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the GroovyDSL scripting framework

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness

Comment: Wow, looks involved, but seems to do what I want - I'll give it a go, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

its possible to save a *.gdsl file somethere in src dir, with content:

```
contributor(context()) {

def scope = com.intellij.psi.search.GlobalSearchScope.allScope(project);
delegatesTo(com.intellij.psi.JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(project).findClass('org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi', scope))    delegatesTo(com.intellij.psi.JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(project).findClass('org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity', scope))}
```